# Which version should i use?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have an old netbook and I wanna use it again.

It's a Positivo Mobile, MOBO M900.

Netbook setup:

- 1.2ghz processor
- 512 mb ram
- 4gb hd
- winXP

Is there any linux distro that I can use?

I have an USB stick with ubuntu 12.04, but since it needs more than 4gb HD, it doesnt even starts the installation.

I booted my netbook from USB and pressed "try before installing" and "install ubuntu"; on both options, the only thing that happened was the netbook showing a black screen for more than 1h.

Comment: Try [antix](http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), don't think an Ubutnu distro will work well on that hardware.

Comment: Lubuntu or Xubuntu might work ok.

Answer (score 1):

puppy Linux will work for you as it has very low minimum system requirements and requires only 128 MB of RAM, although at least 256 MB of RAM is recommended. It offers the most basic applications you’d expect — an extremely lightweight web browser named Dillo, and other programs like an email client, media player, text editor, and image editor. It uses the Openbox window manager by default. and it runs from ram when booted so no worry about old HDD performance.

[image]

[click here to go to puppy Linux website](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm)